# App crashes while Recording in Instruments

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, memory-leaks, xcode-instruments

I am trying to run Instruments on my app, as soon as I click record the app launches and crashes with following error:

```
-[__NSCFString _stringByResolvingSymlinksInPathUsingCache:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

But when runs fine when installed and run using Xcode directly (without Instruments).

It is happening on Simulator as well as iPhone.

Xcode version: 10.2

MacOS: 10.14.4

---

**RESOLVED:** Upgraded to Xcode11 and not facing this issue anymore.

Comment: Show the code only error won't help because there are lots of questions on SO related to this error

Comment: same issue facing

Comment: i am facing the same issue on iPhoneX

Comment: for me time is working on instruments but crash on allocation and leaks

Comment: Exactly the same. Any updates? It crashes when I run Allocations

Comment: RESOLVED: I am now using Xcode11 and not facing this issue there.

Answer (score 0):

After trying many things, switching to an iOS 12.0 simulator was ultimately what got things working for me.  I never figured out the root cause though, so YMMV.

I was originally using Xcode 10.2.1 and building for an iOS 12.2 simulator when I ran into this issue.  I first tried cleaning the build folder, erasing the simulator, and updating to Xcode 10.3 but got the same error each time.  If simply switching to a 12.0 simulator doesn't work for you, try some of those options!

Answer (score 0):

I do believe it is something related to the Certificate signing 
it seems that you are running on Xcode that you didn't configure the provisioning profile on